# How do I open the Orchard project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, orchardcms

Loading it in VS 2010 throws many errors, though it does finally, albeit partially, load.

Also, the .PROJ file was not recognized by Windows at all, I opened the .SLN file in the /src folder but that threw tons of errors when loading up in VS web express 2010. Is that the problem? Do I need full version VS 2010?

Comment: Have you managed to get it up and running?

Comment: If answers were helpful to you - please mark them as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Have you enlisted the **full source code** from Codeplex as described [here](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Setting-up-a-source-enlistment.ashx)? If you want to work with the source (eg. for module development) you **should** fetch the full source and not use the prebuilt package, which is intended for server deployment.

Also, I'd advise you to read [this article](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Building-and-deploying-Orchard-from-a-source-code-drop.ashx) about building Orchard from source. Visual Web Developer 2010 Express should work perfectly (as Orchard can be built without having VS at all).

It's ok that .proj file was not recognized - it's just an MSBuild XML file for automating the build process. You almost never have to touch those.